# Proper USB micro splitter?

Tags: usb, tablet

For my noname low-cost android tablet i'd like to power and use keyboard at the same time - both have USB micro connector on it. But the problem is, that the tablet has only 1 usb micro socket, which gives me lotta trouble. I tried to do male - female - female adapter on my own (without OTG) and it just didn't work out. Guess that even charger uses communication lines to the tablet.

What can I use then, is there any finished solution out there, that's ready to use for this situation?

Comment: Micro USB has special pin that is dedicated to USB OTG. If it is missing the device can not recognize that an USB OTG device is connected.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that. But is there a finished product for this kind of USB "splitter" or is too specific to be "bought"?

Comment: it will never work. that are two different modes that can not used simultaneously (except for some corner cases) https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=otg+charge

Comment: i have two of these [OTG charge HUB](http://g03.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ucQdFVXXXXbJaXXXq6xXFXXX0/4-in-1-Micro-USB-OTG-Charge-HUB-Cable-for-Laptop-Smartphone-Table-Hot.jpg)s (micro USB, USB-C) it has switch for easy changing modes. you can't charge while in host mode, but it provides external power for connected mouse + keyboard + hard disk drive (helpful to increase battery up time)